# How to bind button Content to Dynamic Resource programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, code-behind

I am trying to bind programmatically the Content property of my WPF Button to a Dynamic Resource (Business Object) I have previously defined using a given Path. So far I tried the following approaches with no luck:

My Business Object is defined as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <env:PartyType x:Key="myParty" FullName="JOHN"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I tried binding to my button programmatically like this:

```
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = this.Resources["myParty"];
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FullName");
        btn.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);
```

But apparently when I serialize to XAML its trying to serialize the whole Party Object, and I just want to keep a binding reference to my resource, so this option doesn't work.
My second option was:

```
btn.SetResourceReference(ContentProperty,"myParty");
```

That gets serialized to XAML as:

```
<av:Button Content="{av:DynamicResource myParty}"/>
```

But I don't know how to specify my Path=FullName so it can display the `Party.FullName` and not the `Party.Type()`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the dynamic resource to the `DataContext` and then create your binding without setting the `Source` property

```
btn.SetResourceReference(DataContextProperty,"myParty");

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FullName");
btn.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);
```

Now if you already depand on the button's `DataContext`, then you need set a `Label` as the button's content and set the resource and binding on the label.

Comment: Thanks Simon, that part worked fine. Now, I decided to set the DataContext in the XAML for the parent control (Canvas). Everything works fine, but when I Load the serialized XAML it doesn't show the bound data, any ideas on what could it be?

Comment: @AdolfoPerez, Does the serialized XAML include the binding? My only guess is that the binding is not being serialized.

Comment: Yes, the Serialized XAML includes the binding as follows: `<av:Button Content="{av:Binding Path=FullName, Source={x:Null}}"` When I inspect my regenerated object it does include the binding, but for some reason   the Content is set to null

Comment: Hmm, try looking for binding errors in the output window. Some time back I wrote an article on debuggeing data bindings you can find it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244107/Debugging-WPF-data-bindings), I think it should allow you to figure out why the binding doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I'll have to do that. Thanks again for all your help @SimonBangKerkildsen